# fullpage.js - allow normal scrolling up when scrolling up

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

Using fullpage.js, is it possible to enable normal scrolling when scrolling up but keep the default "one slide per scroll" functionality when scrolling down?

I tried the following but doesn't seem to work:

```
$('.full-page').fullpage({
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {

        if (direction == 'down') {
            $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true);
        }

        else {
            $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fullPage.js doesn't provide such feature. Feel free to create a recommendation for that in the [github issues forum](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues).